# Is it OK to copy pretty much all the content of a community wiki to your blog; then edit lots of your answers to link to it?

Tags: discussion

Is it OK to copy pretty much all the content of a community wiki to your blog; then edit lots of your answers to link to it?  Some pretty decent answers really; but is it spam?

References:
[jQuery Mobile: document ready vs page events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events/14469041#14469041)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848600/gajotres?tab=activity&sort=revisions

http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/

Comment: The article does not even seem related to some of the questions... in which it is linked

Comment: 140 edits in 3 hours hm. It's worth mentioning that user wrote these wiki, before copying to their blog, it's not like they're stealing from someone else\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time somebody is linking to their personal website an excessive amount or in irrelevant situations, that is spam.

This is also bad for two other reasons:

- If the exact same answer applies, it should be closed as a duplicate, not answered
- Even if the question ought to remain open, answers should attempt to include as much information as possible *within the answer*, and only link to an outside site as additional information. The answer should stand on its own.

Additionally, this user is violating the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service). Although all content on Stack Exchange is licensed under a free Creative Commons license, [attribution is required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). This author has not given any attribution to the original question/answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: for the sake of precision, [edited answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1848600/gajotres?tab=activity&sort=revisions) asked about look like perfectly capable of standing on their own; edits just add stuff like "...or read _here_"; "...also look _here_"

Comment: It really is apparent that the SO wiki predates the blog post.

Comment: @gnat true, but that still seems spammy to me. There's no need for him to do that - it does literally nothing to enhance the answer, and therefore is spam in my opinion.

Comment: @gnat most of the time the link is not even related to the issue.

Comment: agree, these edits smell bad

Comment: OK, based on the feedback I am going to accept this answer with the combination of other posts here on Meta with "Acceptable within constraints, but this particular noted instance is not a good example of how to do this effectively and smells of spam/bad practice."